# Remove part of the url by regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
url(http:\/\/localhost\/cards\/media\/images\/designs\/backgrounds\/default\/1.jpg)
```

now i want to remove `url(http:\/\/localhost\/cards\/`

The biggest issue is that it can change all the time, but this part `/media\/images\/designs\/backgrounds\` going to stay same all the time, so i guess i need to match everything until `media` but i don't know regex so well, so i need some help with it :)

Also this should be done with `js` or `jquery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = 'http:\/\/localhost\/cards\/media\/images\/designs\/backgrounds\/default\/1.jpg';
var start = url.indexOf('/media');
var result = url.substr(start);

​alert(result);​
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/THJQm/)

Comment: thank you it works perfectly, and you didn't even use regex, that's nice.

Comment: Yeah for certain situations (mainly since I can't think in terms of regex perfectly yet), I always do something like this!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

`string.replace(/.*(?=\/media\/images\/designs\/backgrounds\/default\/1.jpg)/i,"");`

Comment: Sorry you didn't understood my question, but still thank you for trying to help :)

Comment: Sorry, changed it to what I _should_ have typed.  This one is a regex with a positive lookahead.